# R: Converting integer to factor returns <NA>

Tags: r, na

I have a vector `vec`. It is an integer:

```
dput(vec)
c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L)
```

I can convert it to a factor and add levels in separate steps

```
vec.fac <- factor(vec)
levels(vec.fac) <- c("A", "B")
```

but when I try this in a single step

```
factor(vec, levels = c("A", "B"))
```

every value becomes `<NA>`.

**Question:** Why do these approaches produce different outcomes?

Comment: The `levels` argument of `factor` refers to what is present already, and is generally used to specify an order for the levels, add additional possibilities that may not be present in the data, or to deliberately omit values so they will be coded as `NA`. You can change the labels for the levels with the `labels` argument. `factor(vec, labels = c("A", "B"))`. See `?factor` for details and examples.

Comment: Also see `?levels`

Answer (score 4):

You need to be very careful when converting integers to factors. Sometimes you are safe, but other times ...

Consider the following situation where we have data from an attitude or opinion questionnaire where responses range from 0 to 3. Values of 0 represent "Strongly disagree", 1="Strongly disagree", 2="Agree" and 3="Strongly agree". Imagine "A" is "Strongly disagree" and "D" is "Strongly agree. The data were entered as integers.

Here are the results:

```
vec <- c(1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 3L) 

table(vec)

vec
0 1 3 
5 4 1
```

So most strongly disagreed or disagreed and 1 person strongly agreed but no one agreed. Naive use of the `factor` function results in problems. Here we see only three values (opinions), so we assign three levels.

```
vec.f <- factor(vec)
levels(vec.f) <- c("A","B","C")  # No error
table(vec.f)

vec.f
A B C  # But incorrect label assigment 
5 4 1
```

Even if we assign the correct number of labels, we still get the wrong result.

```
vec.f <- factor(vec)
levels(vec.f) <- c("A","B","C","D")
table(vec.f)

vec.f
A B C D 
5 4 1 0
```

If using this method, the correct way is to use a list describing the mapping.

```
vec.f <- factor(vec)
levels(vec.f) <- list("A"="0", "B"="1", "C"="2", "D"="3")
table(vec.f)

vec.f
A B C D 
5 4 0 1
```

The alternative is to use the `levels` argument of the factor function, which is (as stated in the help page) "an optional vector of the unique values (as character strings) **that x might have taken**".

```
table(factor(vec, labels = c("A","B","C","D"), levels=c("0", "1", "2", "3")))

A B C D 
5 4 0 1
```

Note that without specifying the levels, you'll get an error.

```
table(factor(vec, labels = c("A","B","C","D")))
# Error in factor(vec, labels = c("A", "B", "C", "D")) : 
#  invalid 'labels'; length 4 should be 1 or 3
```

And the following is also incorrect:

```
table(factor(vec, levels=c("A", "B", "C", "D")))

A B C D 
0 0 0 0
```